# Using appendTo multiple time slows down Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendchild, appendto

```
function pp(){
$(document).xpath("//*[@id='Form1']/div[3]/div[1]/img").attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/uo5RuFX.png").clone().appendTo("body");
   $("#BreadCrumb_pnlResults").clone().appendTo("body");




      }
```

I want to execute the above code multiple time but with each execution the performance slows down to point where the script becomes unresponsive.
Is there is any better way to execute the above code.
I heard about

```
createDocumentFragment();
```

but I don't know how to use it in my code
Please help

Comment: is it done multiple time in one go or user input is involved before appending everytime?

Comment: Why on earth are you using XPath, out of (baffled) curiosity?

Comment: Also cloning an element with an id and appending *without* giving a new id leaves your DOM in a bad state.

Comment: After each user input ,the result will be appended to the page @gurvinder372

Comment: I am using [link](https://rawgit.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath/master/jquery.xpath.js) for xpath,
I am using it because the element which I want to access,doesn't have it's own id.

Comment: I just want that my script doesn't slows down @Pointy

Comment: I suspect the xpath slow down the query on a modified DOM.

Comment: Thanks for letting me @Baro

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working i used this

```
function pp(){
frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var body = document.body;
var kp =   document.getElementById("IDName").cloneNode(true);
var ppma = frag.appendChild(kp);
body.appendChild(ppma);
}
```